Complex interpolation between Sobolev spaces
In the book "Nonlinear Dispersive Equations: Local and Global Analysis" by Terence Tao we have the following lemma.
Let $K : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that away from the origin $K$ is smooth and bounded with
$$ |\nabla K(x)| \lesssim |x|^{-1} \, .$$
Then
$$
\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} u(x) K(x) \nabla v(x) \, \textrm{d} x\right| \lesssim\|u\|_{\dot{H}^s\left(\mathbb{R}^d\right)}\|v\|_{\dot{H}^{1-s}\left(\mathbb{R}^d\right)}
$$
for all $u, v \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $s \in [0, 1]$.
According to the textbook it suffices to prove the endpoint cases, i.e. $s = 0$ and $s = 1$ and use "real or complex interpolation" to conclude but I can't figure out the interpolation argument being used. Can anyone help?

He is using the complex interpolation result $[H^0, H^1]_s = H^s$. See section 4.2 of https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-031-33859-5 and chapter 2 of https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-88-7642-638-4
